# AngularJS IF ELSE with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new in AngularJS.

I just need to ask that I am fetching data from the server like that.

```
$http.get(url+'example.php?get=data').
    then(function(response) {
         $scope.data = response.data.my_data;
    });
```

Now I am using this data in `ng-repeat` like in below.

```
ng-repeat="articles in data.article" and like that.
```

Now my question is that suppose my angular variable `data.article` is empty. So it will give that sorry there is no article otherwise it will go on `ng-repeat` loop. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `ng-if` to validate and show message

```
<div ng-repeat="articles in data.article">
  // what ever your content
</div>
<div ng-if="!data.article && data.article.length == 0">
 <span> array is empty </span>
</div>
```

Comment: It is working data.article.length == 0 but it !data.article doesn't.

Comment: if `data.article` property always exist, then remove it

Answer (score 2):

```
$scope.isLoaded = false;

$http.get(url+'example.php?get=data').
    then(function(response) {
         $scope.isLoaded = true;
         $scope.data = response.data.my_data;
    });


<div data-ng-if="isLoaded && data.article"> Sorry, nothing found</div>
```